# Modifying dates in a PHP array

Tags: php, arrays, date, strtotime

I'm able to fill an array with the date of every Monday for the next 4 weeks. The problem is when 12am Monday hits, it immediately shifts the dates forward one week. I don't want it to do that until the the end of Monday, like on Tuesday at 12am. Any thoughts?

```
$start = strtotime( "next monday" );
$end = strtotime( "+4 weeks", $start );

while ( $start < $end ) {

    $dates[] = date( "D, M d", $start );
    $start = strtotime( "+1 week", $start );

}
```

Maybe I can leave the array and just change it when I echo them? This is what I'm doing now.

```
<h3><?php echo $dates[0]; ?></h3>
   <p></p>

<h3><?php echo $dates[1]; ?></h3>
   <p></p>
```

and so on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I just added an if statement before the while. If the current day is a Monday it just moves the start date a week into the "past" to make it equal to today's date. Here's the whole thing:

```
$start == strtotime( 'next monday' );

if( date('N') == 1 ) {
    $start = strtotime( '-1 week', $start );
}

$end = strtotime( '+4 weeks', $start );

while ( $start < $end ) {
    $dates[] = date( 'D, M d', $start );
    $start = strtotime( '+1 week', $start );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When I have to deal with date calculation I use Carbon. It is a good choice! https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon

You can set a start date and start calculating. Cool!

Hope it helps!

Comment: This is not an answer so much as a comment.

Comment: Yeah, next time put it in a comment. Interesting library though, thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

Step 1 day back from today

```
$start = strtotime( "-1 day" );
$start = strtotime( "next monday", $start );
```

Comment: - This would only delay the probably by a day.

Comment: i do it due *I don't want it to do that until the the end of Monday, like on Tuesday at 12am*. The answer you accepted use the 1st day of of a week till the last day

Comment: You are right, splash, it didn't fix my problem. I'm still looking for an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem, as you noted, is `strtotime("next monday")` returns *this week's Monday* on Sunday but *next Monday* after Sunday.

It seems you always want *this week's Monday*. As such, you can use the relative time string *monday this week*:

```
$start = strtotime('monday this week');
```

Comment: I thought this fixed it, but I was wrong. I want to display the coming monday, not the monday in this calendar week. If Monday this week has passed, it will show the date for that Monday, not the coming one.